# Does query planner decide on its own when to take Update lock vs Shared lock?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, locking

I have been reading about Update locks in [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-2017), blogs, and stackoverflow. I see examples of queries that use UPDLOCK hint to indicate to query planner to grab an Update lock (usually done to avoid deadlocks in REPEATABLE READ or SERIALIZABLE isolation levels).

1. Does UPDLOCK hint needs to be always specified manually, or are there cases when query planner automatically decides it needs an Update lock instead of a Shared lock?
2. If yes, are there some simple examples where query planner will automatically decide to take an Update lock over Shared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `UpdLock` query hint allow a developer to change the default locking behavior across *multiple* DML statements. The query analyzer has no reason to extend locks from one statement to another, e.g. to intuit that data in a `select` statement is likely to be modified in a subsequent `update` statement as part of reserving seats for tea.

Comment: Thanks. So, it sounds like by supporting update locks, sql server allows users to avoid deadlocks by supporting a way to accept hints from them. However, without the user provided hints (or even with them), the db *can still get* into deadlocks. (and choose a victim to get out of it). So it doesn't *automatically* make the db deadlock free, but it provides means to reduce it. Does that sound right?

Comment: @Turbo That's right. Using locking hints adds a level of granularity between just executing individual DML statements and executing a transaction with an isolation level of `serializable`. You can add semantics that minimize locking and streamline transactions. In some cases you can carefully arrange operations so that deadlocks cannot occur, in others you can minimize them. (At least until some helpful user running ad hoc queries gums up the works.) You can also implement "real time" processes that decline to wait for locks and fail immediately by using the `nowait` hint.